# Database Resume Builder

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb

I am creating a resume database with multiple tables. There is a resume table that includes( name, address, etc), a degree table that includes(school, grad year, gpa, etc) a employment_history table that includes( previous job, etc) and a reference table that includes(reference, phone#, etc) Here are the tables below. Now as you may know, a person may have multiple degrees, or multiple references. I have data in those tables and I have a a query that works. but because I have a person that has multiple degrees, it prints out 4 rows for that one person

```
Select  * 
from Resume AS res, degrees AS deg , Employment_History AS eh
WHERE deg.FK_RESUME_ID = res.ID_NUMBER AND eh.FK_RESUME_ID = res.ID_NUMBER;
```

and it returns

[image]

as you see in the results picture, the results print out 4 rows, but all of the data belong to that one person( same id). I am trying make a query that prints out all of a persons information from all the tables but only on 1 row, not multiple

```
create table resume (
    ID_NUMBER bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    VERSION_ID bigint default 0 not null,
    address varchar(50),
      city varchar(30),
    state varchar(2),
    zip_code varchar(5),
    first_name varchar(30),
      last_name varchar(30),
    best_phone varchar(11),
    email_address varchar(50),
      objective_note varchar(150),
    primary key (ID_NUMBER)
);   

create table degrees (
    ID_NUMBER bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    VERSION_ID bigint default 0 not null,
    School varchar(50),
    degree_type varchar(5),
    major varchar(30),
    grad_month varchar(9),
    grad_year varchar(4),
    gpa varchar(5),
    fk_resume_id bigint not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_resume_id) references resume (ID_NUMBER),
    primary key (ID_NUMBER)
);

create table reference (
    ID_NUMBER bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    VERSION_ID bigint default 0 not null,
    first_name varchar(30),
      last_name varchar(30),
    best_phone varchar(11),
    email_address varchar(50),
    fk_resume_id bigint not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_resume_id) references resume (ID_NUMBER),
    primary key (ID_NUMBER)
);



create table employment_history (
    ID_NUMBER bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
    VERSION_ID bigint default 0 not null,
    company varchar(50),
      title varchar(30),
    duties varchar(100),
    start_month varchar(9),
      start_year varchar(4),
    end_month varchar(9),
      end_year varchar(4),
    fk_resume_id bigint not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_resume_id) references resume (ID_NUMBER),
    primary key (ID_NUMBER)
 );
```

Comment: If you want to return multiple rows in one you might want to have a look at the GROUP_CONCAT function

Comment: @Sergio I agree that `GROUP_CONCAT` is the dead ringer for his problem.  But unfortunately, because of poor wording and no example output, we can't write a query.